# Django - possible to retry any DB operation on failure?

Tags: python, django, database, error-handling

We are having issues recently with our prod servers connecting to Oracle. Intermittently we are getting "DatabaseError: ORA-12502: TNS:listener received no CONNECT_DATA from client". This issue is completely random and goes away in a second by itself and it's not a Django problem, can replicate it with SQLPlus from the servers.

We opened ticket with Oracle support but in the meantime i'm wondering if it's possible to simply retry any DB-related operation when it fails.

**The problem is that i can't use try/catch blocks in the code to handle this since this can happen on ANY DB interaction in the entire codebase. I have to do this at a lower level so that i do it only once**. Is there any way to install an error handler or something like that directly on **django.db.backends.oracle** level so that it will cover all the codebase? Basically, all i want to do is this:

```py
try:
   execute_sql()
catch:
   if code == ORA-12502:
       sleep 1 second
       #re-try the same operation
       exexute_sql()
```

Is this even possible or I'm out of luck?

Thanks!

Comment: I think what you want is to apply a decorator to the relevant Django database function(s). Did you check https://github.com/rholder/retrying and its examples of applying `retry` logic as decorators on Python functions that can fail because of whatever reasons?

Comment: Or maybe use the more up-to-date `tenacity` library to add the retrying logic to your save method(s) by decorating them: https://github.com/jd/tenacity

Comment: @EmreSevinç Looks cool but from what i can see it's just a syntactic sugar over try/catch, right? Again, can't do that since this can happen at any place in the entire codebase. My question is whether Django provides an interface to install some kind of error handler or i have to modify Django source files (which i really don't wanna do...), somewhere here I guess:

site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()

Comment: I think you're on the right track. Maybe you should change the title of your question to something like: "How to install a custom exception handler into Django for database exceptions?" Indeed, it's not a good idea to directly change the source code of Django itself.